# Cross-referencing entries in glossary

Tags: glossaries

I use the \gls{} command to cross-reference in my glossary, which spans multiple pages. However, instead of printing the page number of the page where I had referenced the entry, the first page of the table of contents is printed. I think that it may have something to do with the changing of page numbers from roman to arabic.

Is there any way around this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass [a4paper, 12pt] {report}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[backref=page, hyperfootnotes=false, hidelinks, colorlinks, citecolor=OliveGreen, linkcolor=Blue, linktocpage, bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[toc, nopostdot, nogroupskip]{glossaries}

\newglossarystyle{mylong}{
\setglossarystyle{long}
\renewenvironment{theglossary}
 {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{\dimexpr 8cm-\tabcolsep}p{0.5\hsize}}}
 {\end{longtable}}
 }

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{q}{name=q,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{w}{name=w,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah. Cross-reference \gls{z}}
\newglossaryentry{e}{name=e,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{r}{name=r,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{t}{name=t,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{y}{name=y,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{u}{name=u,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{i}{name=i,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{o}{name=o,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{p}{name=p,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{l}{name=l,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{k}{name=k,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{j}{name=j,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{h}{name=h,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{g}{name=g,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{f}{name=f,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{d}{name=d,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{s}{name=s,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{a}{name=a,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{z}{name=z,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah. Cross-reference \gls{a}}
\newglossaryentry{x}{name=x,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{c}{name=c,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{v}{name=v,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{b}{name=b,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{n}{name=n,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}
\newglossaryentry{m} {name=m,description=blahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblahblah}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\tableofcontents
\phantomsection
\printglossary[style=mylong]
\label{glossary}

\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\gls{q}
\gls{w}
\gls{e}
\gls{r}
\gls{t}
\gls{y}
\gls{u}
\gls{i}
\gls{o}
\gls{p}
\gls{l}
\gls{k}
\gls{j}
\gls{h}
\gls{g}
\gls{f}
\gls{d}
\gls{s}
\gls{a}
\gls{z}
\gls{x}
\gls{c}
\gls{v}
\gls{b}
\gls{n}
\gls{m}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I run this for entries such as `a` I get two page numbers: `iii` and `1`. The reason for this is that there is a `\gls{a}` command on page `1` AND a `\gls{a}` appearing as a cross-reference in the glossary on page `iii`. I think that this is correct.

Comment: It seems that deleting the aux files and running makeindex again worked for me for the MWE. It however did not work for my actual tex file. I will attempt to make a better MWE. Thanks for your help, Andrew.